# I'm trying to get 1 button to control both play and pause, can someone help me?

Tags: html, html5-audio

I'm trying to get 1 button to control both play and pause, can someone help me? And I really want to do it using the code-set below. Hope someone will be able to help with this. https://jsfiddle.net/8e68js93/1/

I know of this code, but I don't know how to incorporate it in the below codes. **[**`this.paused?this.play():this.pause();` **]** And if it can't be used with the below codes, I don't want to use it.

```
<audio id="player" src="http://hi5.1980s.fm/;"></audio>
    <div>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Play</button>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()">Pause</button>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause() ;document.getElementById('player').currentTime=0;">Stop</button>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').muted=!document.getElementById('player').muted">Mute/ Unmute</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <audio id="player" src="http://hi5.1980s.fm/;"></audio>
    <div>
        <button onclick="togglePlay()">Play</button>
        <button onclick="togglePlay()">Pause</button>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause();document.getElementById('player').currentTime = 0;">Stop</button>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').muted = !document.getElementById('player').muted">Mute/ Unmute</button>
    </div>

    <script>
        function togglePlay() {
            var player = document.getElementById('player');
            if (player.paused) {
                player.play();
            } else {
                player.pause();
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Or all inline:

```
<button onclick="var player = document.getElementById('player'); player.paused ? player.play() : player.pause()">Play</button>
```

Comment: Does it have to use javascript?

Comment: Yes. Your version is using javascript too. You want me to do it all inline?

Comment: How would I incorporate it using this code, so it goes back and forth play / pause? https://jsfiddle.net/wsotbk9s/16/ So it switches back and forth, the text and background when you click on it. And thank you for your help!

Comment: Thats starting to get really sloppy looking. Use a function to change the styles. Check out the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/wsotbk9s/23/

Comment: Is there an inline code for that also? Would that be possible? Like how you did with the other code?

Comment: You could just copy the inside of the function and put it inside the onclick handler, but why would you want to do that?

Comment: Can you show me an inline code for it? How it would look, the set up of it. I'm new at coding, so I'm learning as I code. But I would like to see how an inline code would look.

Comment: If I have 2 different styles, how do I separate them? https://jsfiddle.net/wsotbk9s/28/ And this is your code. https://jsfiddle.net/wsotbk9s/24/

Comment: Can you show me how I can use an image to work as a button? http://i.imgur.com/hARohAn.png / https://jsfiddle.net/wsotbk9s/36/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use jQuery for this.